# Hacked by ruined@india.com

Tags: windows, security, azure, hacking

I was happily working on my Azure VM playpen last night via a remote desktop session. When I logged on this morning I was presented with the attached message:

[image: hacked pic]

The VM contained nothing of value and the study app I was working on was committed to a remote repo. So while I can easily delete this VM and create another, I am interested in ideas as to how this may have happened. I guess it could just be brute force password attack. Anyone else seen the same on an Azure VM?

Comment: Brute force, malware on your personal computer, vulnerable installed applications, the list goes on and on.

Comment: This should be deleted for several reasons: It is better suited for Information Security than Server Fault, it does not have a defined answer, it is largely based on opinion, it is an exact duplicate, and it does not reflect professional standards.  I would suggest deleting it.

Comment: I agree with each point here

Comment: Thanks @ceejayoz I guess I'll never know but all good suggestions